# Java Swing lay out components from top to bottom

Tags: java, swing

I need to place 1 JLabel and 6 JCheckbox from top to bottom and the label should be centered and the checkboxes should not. 
I tried two options:

1. Using GridBagLayout
2. Using BoxLayout

When using the first option everything goes fine, but the content is in the middle of the JPanel. When using the second option, content goes from top to bottom, but the JLabel is not centered. What do I need to do make it work?

People also advise to set `gbc.weighty = 1.0`, but components just fill all available space in container.

Runnable example with GridBagLayout:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel root = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel filterPanel = new JPanel();
        filterPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        JLabel filterLabel = new JLabel("Filter");
        filterLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        filterPanel.add(filterLabel, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

        JCheckBox releasesBox = new JCheckBox("Releases");
        JCheckBox snapshotsBox = new JCheckBox("Snapshots");
        JCheckBox oldSnapshotsBox = new JCheckBox("Old Snapshots");
        JCheckBox betasBox = new JCheckBox("Betas");
        JCheckBox alphasBox = new JCheckBox("Alphas");
        JCheckBox experimentsBox = new JCheckBox("Experiments");

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        filterPanel.add(releasesBox, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        filterPanel.add(snapshotsBox, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        filterPanel.add(oldSnapshotsBox, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        filterPanel.add(betasBox, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        filterPanel.add(alphasBox, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        filterPanel.add(experimentsBox, gbc);

        root.add(filterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.add(root, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Runnable example with BoxLayout:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel root = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel filterPanel = new JPanel();
        filterPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(filterPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JLabel filterLabel = new JLabel("Filter");
        // Adding this line makes it only worse
        // filterLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        filterPanel.add(filterLabel);

        JCheckBox releasesBox = new JCheckBox("Releases");
        JCheckBox snapshotsBox = new JCheckBox("Snapshots");
        JCheckBox oldSnapshotsBox = new JCheckBox("Old Snapshots");
        JCheckBox betasBox = new JCheckBox("Betas");
        JCheckBox alphasBox = new JCheckBox("Alphas");
        JCheckBox experimentsBox = new JCheckBox("Experiments");

        filterPanel.add(releasesBox);
        filterPanel.add(snapshotsBox);
        filterPanel.add(oldSnapshotsBox);
        filterPanel.add(betasBox);
        filterPanel.add(alphasBox);
        filterPanel.add(experimentsBox);

        root.add(filterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.add(root, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: not a direct answer to your problem, but maybe a helpful resource: an old [visual guide to layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: You know you can use more than one layout manager at a time, right? Try nesting layout managers, i.e. BoxLayout as a component within GridBagLayout, for example. GridBagLayout allows you to have a component span multiple cells, which keeps you from having a lot of dead space in your UI.

Comment: `GridBagLayout` solution: for the last element, change `gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;` and `gbc.weighty = 1.0;` (only before adding the last element, so it alone will get all space)

Comment: @user16320675, Thanks, it works! You can write answer, I will accept it.